# Facebook Marketing API, Version 2.8 error despite 2.8 in composer.json

Tags: php, json, facebook, version, facebook-marketing-api

I am programming a Marketing-API for facebook and am running into the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
    'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException'
with message
    '(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API.
    Please update to the latest version: v2.8.'
in [MY FOLDER]/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:163
```

Here is the file `[MY FOLDER]/composer.json` I used to install the SDKs:

```
{
  "require": {
      "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
      "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.*"
   }
}
```

Within the app folder (which I upload to a private server, from `/localhost/~[my user name]/[some directory]/`, henceforth referred to as `[MY FOLDER]`) I have two `php` files `index.php` and `login-callback.php` as well as the sdks (facebook & facebook-ads) located in `[MY FOLDER]/vendor`. Here are the `php` files:

File `[MY FOLDER]/index.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\Facebook;
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => '000000000000', // censored
    'app_secret' => '000000000000', // censored
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['ads_management'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('[MY FOLDER]/login-callback.php',$permissions);
?>
```

File `[MY FOLDER]/login-callback.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\Authentification\AccessToken;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook([
'app_id' => '000000000000', // censored
'app_secret' => '000000000000', // censored
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
// This is actually wrapped in a try-catch control group
// I have left it out for this question, as there are no problems
// in this respect and the clauses are really long.
Api::init(
$app_id,
$app_key,
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
);
$campaign = new Campaign('000000000000'); // censored
try {
    $campaign->read(array(
        CampaignFields::ID,
        CampaignFields::NAME,
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
    ));
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // error with Graph API
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // error with Facebook SDK
    exit;
}
?>
```

The error occurs when trying to call `$campaign->read(array(···))`. The SDK returns the error above together with the tracking:

```
Stack trace:
#0 [API-FOLDER]/Http/Client.php
    (217): FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException::create(Array, 400)
#1 [API-FOLDER]/Http/Request.php
    (282): FacebookAds\Http\Client->sendRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#2 [API-FOLDER]/Api.php
    (152): FacebookAds\Http\Request->execute()
#3 [API-FOLDER]/Api.php
    (194): FacebookAds\
in [API-FOLDER]/Http/Exception/RequestException.php
    on line 163
```

Here `[API-FOLDER]` = `[MY FOLDER]/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src`.

Note the demand in the error: *...Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.8.* But I have done this. Can someone please tell me, what on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a(n annoying) solution. I went to github and manually downloaded the latest version.

This is ridiculous. I followed the official installation instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks (create `composer.json` file incl. explicit version details —> execute terminal command `php composer.phar install --no-dev`). I don’t see why this does not work.

**Has anyone else encountered this problem?** Or am I one of the few, for whom automatic installation did not lead to the right version?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have to do with the login part. When initializing the Facebook class here,

```
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => '000000000000', // censored
  'app_secret' => '000000000000', // censored
]);
```

you did not specify the API version to use - so it falls back to the lowest API version your app can use. Likely that messes up things later when you use the resulting token to make calls to the Marketing API.

Try and explicitly specify the API version to use,

```
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => '000000000000', // censored
  'app_secret' => '000000000000', // censored
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);
```

Comment: Working with the state of things after following the SDK-installation instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks this has no effect. Having manually downloaded v2.8 of the SDK from GIT-Hub, adding or removing `'default_graph_version' =>  'v2.8'` has no effect. Conclusion: the facebook installation instructions are faulty, one has to download the SDK manually.